# How do i monitor disturb processes which use perf_event_open profiling PMU data

Tags: c++, c, linux, kernel, perf

I want to use perf_event_open to sample PMU data. But i don‘t want to sample if there is other processes use the PMU counter. is there some way to monitor the use of PMU registers by other processes

Comment: PAPI virtualizes the PMU.  That's why `perf stat` can count stuff for just one process, rather than only in system-wide mode.  Are you using system-wide mode, and don't want to multiplex counters?  I think the `perf` shell command has to manually multiplex, so I assume it would just fail if you tried to open but they were already busy.  So what actual problem are you trying to solve with this check?

Comment: If multiple processes collect PMU data at the same time, it will lead to PMU data inaccurate, and multiplex counters  may  increase interrupt. Therefore, I hope to detect whether any process is occupying PMU, and decide whether to do data collection.

Comment: You could use `exclusive=1` in your `perf_event_attr` if you want to stop the kernel from doing any funny stuff while this event is being counted, such as multiplexing.  (You're right, it seems the kernel takes care of multiplexing, not just the user-space `perf` tool, my mistake in the earlier comment.)